# How to update Activity from thread started in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a Main activity and after click on button I start thread (but the thread is hidden in library and I have only callback in Main activity. 
Now I want to start another activity (call A) where I want to put results from the thread. 
Below is simplified code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {


    XManager.ResultsCallback xResultsCallback = new XManager.ResultsCallback() {

// the method is called every 10 sec. 
        @Override
        public void onResult(ArrayList<String> texts) {


        }
    };

    XManager xManager = new xManager(xResultsCallback);
    View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            XManager.start();

            Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, A.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    };


}
```

I want to update the content of A activity each time when onResult() method is called. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LocalBroadcastManager,

In your **Main** Activity create function :

```
private void sendResult() {
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "This is my result!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and add BroadcastReceiver in your **A** Activity

```
private BroadcastReceiver onResult= new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("jazzy","onReceive called");

    }
};
```

add on **OnCreate**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Register to receive messages.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}
```

add **onDestroy**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I find it but it is from support library. Is any "normal" solution?

Comment: Make your XManager a singelton class, and call him from any place you want. in addition in every activity you can register a callback to the desired result like : 

xManager.getInstance().addCallback(new Callback(){
..
})

Inside xManager create a List<Callbacks> list;

private void addCallback(Callback callback)
{
list.add(callback)
}

and call the all the callbacks when your thread is done the work.

private void callAll()
{ for(Callback  : callback : list)
callback.call(..params...)

}

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that you should do as follows:

1. Start Your `Activity A` on button click
2. Inside Activity A declare your `XManager` instance with a callback present in `A` itself
3. Then start your `XManager` as `XManager.start();` that way you would be getting all the callbacks in your desired activity.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to decouple the logic, beside you can use the Android BroadcastReceiver, the another flexible choice is to use the [Bus](http://square.github.io/otto/)

And you can integrate it with gradle easily

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.squareup:otto:+'
}
```